# In hydra-python structured configs, how do you interpolate values?

Tags: fb-hydra

I am using structured config (`@dataclass`-based) with hydra 1.1 and trying to interpolate some values. Specifically, I would like to set the working directory by substituting some of my config values.

I was able to do this consulting the [documentation](https://hydra.cc/docs/configure_hydra/workdir) when using yaml:

```
run:
  dir: outputs
  name: try1

hydra:
  run:
    dir: ${run.dir}/${run.name}
```

How can I do this using structured configs?

Comment: Which part of your config above are you trying to replace with a structured config? Do you want to replace the `"run"` part that contains the `"outputs"` and `"try1"` strings, or do you want to replace the `"hydra"` part that contains the interpolation?

Comment: The "hydra" part. I would like the run directory to be dynamically changed as I give a nickname (`try1`) to my experiment. In the above example, I want `hydra.run.dir` to be `outputs/try1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to create a structured config that can be used to override Hydra's default output directory.

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
  - my_run_dir
  - _self_

run:
  dir: outputs
  name: try1
```

```py
# my_app.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import hydra
from hydra.conf import RunDir
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore

cs = ConfigStore.instance()

@dataclass
class MyRunDir(RunDir):
    dir: str = "${run.dir}/${run.name}"

cs.store(name="my_run_dir", node=MyRunDir, package="hydra.run")

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    from hydra.core.hydra_config import HydraConfig
    assert HydraConfig.get().run.dir == "outputs/try1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

When this python file is run, the directory `outputs/try1` is created.

As an alternative to using the `package="hydra.run"` keyword argument to the `cs.store` method call, you could use an "@package" defaults list entry from `config.yaml`:

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
  - my_run_dir@hydra.run
...
```

```py
# my_app.py
...
cs.store(name="my_run_dir", node=MyRunDir)  # omit the `package=` argument
...
```

See the Hydra docs on [Packages](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages) for more info on this.